# VueJS not working with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-resource

Posting vue data as body to post request using vue resource

```
<script>
    //var VueValidator = require ('vue-validator');
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
            uid: '{{$row->id}}'
        },
        methods: {
            changeCredentials: function (e) {
                console.log(this.email); --> **RETURNS EMPTY**
                var resource = this.$resource('myurl/{id}');
                resource.save({id: this.uid}, {body: function () {
                    console.log(this.data);
                    return this.data;
                }}).then((response) => {
                    // success callback
                    console.log(response);
                }, (response) => {
                    // error callback
                });


                //alert('here');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Can you tell me why this.uid is working but not this.email? Thanks

Comment: Did you bind your `email` correctly by using v-model?

Comment: For sure, please provide your post with email binding code. Because by the moment i see only `uid: '{{$row->id}}'` this binding. And `email: ''` stays empty.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you're accessing `this.data` you're inside a callback which changes the scope you're currently in, where `this` is not actually your Vue component.

By setting `_this` you may then access that variable once you scope changes and you move into the callback.

```
changeCredentials: function () {
    var resource = this.$resource('myurl/{id}');
    var _this = this;

    resource.save({id: _this.uid}, {body: function () {
        console.log(_this.data);

        return _this.data;
    }});
}
```